# WSO2 DAS REST API using JQuery crashes on "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check"

Tags: jquery, rest, wso2, cors, wso2-das

I try to use a the WSO2 DAS 3.0 REST API to retreive some data from my store. The API works fine using SoapUI or Chrome extension REST client. However called from javascript using JQuery's Ajax it fail on the same origin policy.

I added the filter to the web.xml on the server side as described in documentation:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The call looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:9443/analytics/search',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "tableName":"TEST",
        "query":"*:*",
        "start":0,
        "count":100
    },
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(1);
        //console.info(data);
    }
});
```

However the allowed origin is not applied as visible from the error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:9443/analytics/search. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myserver' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Anyone sucessfull calling the API using JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is as simple as adding an additional param to the server-side filter as JQuery tends to send allow-origin related headers in the preflight request. The configuration should look like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```