# WSO2 Api Manger 3.0.0 Token API CORS issue with Angular Application

Tags: cors, wso2, api-manager

I have been using WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0 single node setup. I am facing the challenge of invocation of Token APIs ( available at https://host:port/token?grant_type=client_credentials) that are used to get the token. After checking few blogs I have identified a couple of files requires changes. Theses are-

```
Files: _TokenAPI_.xml and _RevokeAPI_.xml 
Files Location: /usr/lib64/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api
```

I have made the changes as per the below code -

```
<handlers>
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
        <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
        <property name="allowHeaders" value="authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction"/>
        <property name="allowedOrigins" value="*"/>
        <property name="AuthorizationHeader" value="Authorization"/>
        <property name="allowedMethods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
        <property name="allowCredentials" value="true"/>
    </handler>
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler"/>
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

I am using Angular application to invoke the token API but the invocation is still not successful and causing CORS issue. I have also tried to remove Underscore( _ ) from file names and renamed them as TokenAPI.xml and RevokeAPI.xml but still no luck. Can you please assist.Below is the complete XML for

```
_TokenAPI_.xml
```

```html
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPI_" context="/token">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="uri.var.portnum" expression="get-property('keyManager.port')"/>
     <property name="uri.var.hostname" expression="get-property('keyManager.hostname')"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                     <http uri-template="https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>60000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
            <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
            <property name="allowHeaders" value="authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction"/>
            <property name="allowedOrigins" value="*"/>
            <property name="AuthorizationHeader" value="Authorization"/>
            <property name="allowedMethods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
            <property name="allowCredentials" value="true"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

XHR information is as below-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[EDIT]
My API Manager and Angular Application is running on different environment i.e. different virtual machines.

Comment: What are the exact error messages that your browser is logging in the devtools console? What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Error message is - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://49.50.x.x:8243/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Pls see updated question with additional screenshots.

Comment: @sideshowbarker HTTP status code is 200

Comment: So, that error message and the screenshot edits in the question indicate that you need to update your server system to ensure that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header gets added to OPTIONS responses. For help with that, maybe see the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108369/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878196/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34293921/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172926/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker, thanks a lot for your time.However, I have seen the possible solution links. I have already tried the changes in _Token_.xml, _Revoke_.xml by adding CORS handlers(code specified in question) In addition I am using wso2 api 3.0.0 so all possible values of corresponding XML has been correctly specified. Even I tried to modify web.xml inside /conf/tomcat by adding CORS filter at the bottom of xml files but no luck. Still facing CORS issue. Any other lead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API gateway CORS handler

```xml
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
```

in token API as well. Once added your `_TokenAPI_.xml` file should look like below

```xml
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPI_" context="/token">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="uri.var.portnum" expression="get-property('keyManager.port')"/>
        <property name="uri.var.hostname" expression="get-property('keyManager.hostname')"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                     <http uri-template="https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>60000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
            <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
            <property name="AuthorizationHeader" value="Authorization"/>
        </handler>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution worked. Same solution also available at https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7057